# Database Design: What is the best structure for storing site offices and locations?

Tags: mysql, database-design

**Background**

I am creating a database driven web application for the management team at the place I work. Part of this application requires fairly specific locations to be linked with where equipment resides. The RDBMS that will be used is MySQL.

The site has 5 major zones labelled Black, Blue, Gold, Green and Red. Within each zone are several offices, generally referred to as Blue 57, Gold 155 etc. Along with the offices are rooms such as cleaner's cupboards, toilets and kitchens which have no specific number. There are also a handful of larger spaces which do not technically come under a specific zone.

**The Problem**

My concern here is how best to store all these locations within my database.

I could of course just have a flat table with an ID and Name columns:

```
LocationID        Name

45                Gold 1
46                Gold 2
47                Gold 3
48                Red Kitchen
49                Blue Toilet First Floor
...
```

However, I recognise that there is a huge amount of repetition. Plus if the site changes zone layout, names or office numbering (has happened at least once) it would be a nightmare to fix. So my next thought was to put the major zones and spaces in their own table, so I would have:

```
LocationID        Name                   ZoneID

45                1                      102
46                2                      102
47                3                      102
48                Kitchen                104
49                Toilet First Floor     101
```

```
ZoneID     Zone     

100        Black
101        Blue
102        Gold
103        Green
104        Red
```

This is definitely better, but with certain types of room - toilets, kitchens et al - there is still repetition (no two numbered offices have the same number, i.e. there is no Red 14 and Blue 14).

Is having a small amount of repetition acceptable to keep the tables simple? If I had a third table with stuff like "Kitchen", "Toilet", "Lockers" etc I would need a RoomType foreign key in the Location table. I would then have a situation where some locations have a Name and a null value for the RoomType, or the opposite and have a RoomType value and empty Name value. This doesn't strike me as being ideal.

Is there a way of doing this that avoids too much redundancy but doesn't increase the complexity massively? These tables will mostly be read with updates and inserts rare once the DB is populated.

Comment: It sounds like someone has already classified them as three types: 1) numbered rooms (have a number that is unique across the enterprise), 2) ancillary rooms, 3) larger spaces. We know that numbered rooms and ancillary rooms have a commom attribute ('zone'). I suggest you look for further common attributes between these three types to identify possible supertypes.

Comment: Consider two tables for `NumberedRooms` and `AncillaryRooms` respectively, both with attributes `Name` and `Zone`. Both have a superkey on the compound of `Zone` and `Name` but is a minimal superkey only in `AncillaryRooms`, `Name` being a minimal superkey in `NumberedRooms`. So having them in separate tables is good in terms of constraint enforcement and the common attributes means you can `UNION` them to present them as a supertype, perhaps named `Rooms`. p.s. I recommend in the strongest terms you avoid nullable columns.

Comment: I have asked the question of whether individual ancillary rooms - kitchens etc - have been designated any unique name or number. I hope to hear back soon! In the case of certain other spaces, most, bar a very small few, are in particular zones even if they are not referred to as being there. Those not in a named zone could go into another logical grouping such as "Grounds" or "Car Park" etc. Thanks for your comments so far, it has steered me in a direction to take with this.

Comment: Just a quick question, assuming I have the two tables you describe, `NumberedRooms` and `AncillaryRooms`, how do I reference them with a foreign key from other tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some vanilla SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE RoomTypes
(
 RoomType VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE (RoomType)
);

CREATE TABLE Zones
(
 Zone VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE (Zone)
);

CREATE TABLE Rooms
(
 RoomType VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
 Zone VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
 Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
 UNIQUE (RoomType, Zone, Name), 
 FOREIGN KEY (RoomType) REFERENCES RoomTypes (RoomType),
 FOREIGN KEY (Zone) REFERENCES Zones (Zone)
);

CREATE TABLE NumberedRooms 
(
 RoomType VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
 Zone VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
 Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
 CHECK (RoomType = 'Numbered'),
 UNIQUE (Name), 
 UNIQUE (RoomType, Zone, Name),
 FOREIGN KEY (RoomType, Zone, Name) 
    REFERENCES Rooms (RoomType, Zone, Name)
);

CREATE TABLE AncillaryRooms 
(
 RoomType VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
 Zone VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
 Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
 CHECK (RoomType = 'Ancillary'),
 UNIQUE (Zone, Name), 
 UNIQUE (RoomType, Zone, Name),
 FOREIGN KEY (RoomType, Zone, Name) 
    REFERENCES Rooms (RoomType, Zone, Name)
);
```

The `CHECK` constraints will not be tested by mySQL e.g. do the tests yourself using triggers. Consider adding other tests e.g. that attribute `Name` in table `NumberedRooms` represents an integer.

The idea that every row in the supertype table `Rooms` will have exactly one row in the union of `AncillaryRooms` and `NumberedRooms`. This is merely implied e.g. have 'helper' procs to add rows to both super- and subtype tables as a single operation and use triggers to ensure it is done.

Note `NumberedRooms` has a simple key `Name` alone, whereas `AncillaryRooms` has a compound key on `(Zone, Name)`. All three (non-lookup) tables have a key on `(RoomType, Zone, Name)` throughout, allowing further subtype tables to referencing them and maintain integrity by further testing for valid `RoomType` values.

Comment: Showing my lack of experience here, but with your table structure how would I query for the full location - Zone and its number or name? Similarly if I have a foreign key in an Equipment table do I point it to Rooms? I haven't worked with super/sub-typing so my knowledge is a bit thin (read: absent) in this area.

Comment: @PeterSpain: "how would I query for the full location - Zone and its number or name?" -- `SELECT * FROM Rooms WHERE Zone = 'Red' AND Name = 'Kitchen';`

Comment: "if I have a foreign key in an Equipment table do I point it to Rooms?" -- yes, if there is an association between `Equipment` and all types of rooms, however if, say, there is only an association between  `Equipment` and `AncillaryRooms` then the FK should reference `AncillaryRooms` only.

Comment: Some Equipment can be any room - an air conditioning unit, for example, can be found in offices and the comms room. Networking equipment can be found just about anywhere.

Thank you for your time oneday, this has been a huge help! :)